# Type defined multiple times error when building a .NET MAUI app in Visual Studio with a Java Bindings Library

Tags: .net, visual-studio, maui

I have an Android project which builds in Android Studio and generates multiple .jar files. I've followed the steps described at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar to produce a JarBinding.dll managed callable wrapper built with the R.jar generated from my Android project, (with the R.jar having a build action of EmbeddedJar).

I then updated a .NET MAUI project to add a reference to my JarBinding.dll, but get the following error attempting to build the solution:

Error JAVA0000 Error in obj\Debug\net7.0-android\android\bin\classes.zip:com/google/android/material/R$anim.class: Type com.google.android.material.R$anim is defined multiple times: obj\Debug\net7.0-android\android\bin\classes.zip:com/google/android/material/R$anim.class, obj\Debug\net7.0-android\lp\1\jl\R.jar:com/google/android/material/R$anim.class

I'm not sure whether the source of this problem relates to my Android Studio build settings when generating the original R.jar, or in VS when generating the MCR wrapper, or in VS when referencing the wrapper in my .NET MAUI project. Any suggestions on how to resolve this would be much appreciated.